# How to wait in main UI thread for user interaction without blocking it?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, asynchronous

Assume a scenario where I have an instance method that runs on the main UI thread, adds a custom `UserControl` (WPF) to the main application window that can be accessed via a singleton, and then needs to wait with further execution until the user interacted with that `UserControl` and some value is sent back.

My first attempts would always end up blocking the UI thread, so the user could not actually interact with the `UserControl`, until I eventually came across `async` and `await`.

The following is the simplified gist of the solution that I came up with:

```
Public Class ControlManagerA
    Inherits ControlManagerBase

    Public Property userControlResult As String

    Public Overrides Async Function CreateAndWait() As Task

        'Initialize to some default value to indicate that no response was received yet.
        userControlResult = Nothing

        Dim myCustomControl As New MyCustomUserControlA()
        'Could also pass any additional parameters required for display.
        myCustomControl.AssignParent(Me)

        GlobalUIManager.GetMainWindow().AssignUserControl(myCustomControl)

        'This will eventually be populated with a proper value due to
        'user interaction in MyCustomUserControlA.
        While userControlResult Is Nothing
            'This is the part that I am a little unhappy about.
            Await Task.Delay(1)
        End While

        GlobalUIManager.GetMainWindow().RemoveUserControl(myCustomControl)

        DoSomethingWithResult(userControlResult)

    End Function
End Class
```

The one thing that bothers me about it is that I am busy-waiting in a loop there. (And the fact that I could probably also pass the `userControlResult` as a `ByRef` parameter instead of waiting for `MyCustomUserControlA` to access it via a public property.)
The solution is still working out for me and I don't notice any performance problems at all, but I was wondering if there was a better way to await a result here. I also don't know if `Task.Delay(1)` is wasteful or if it's actually pretty lightweight in terms of overhead.

Comment: It seems like raising an event from `MyCustomUserControlA` that is handled by `ControlManagerA` (or some other callback mechanism) would reduce coupling and simplify things, but maybe I'm not understanding the whole picture?

Comment: The code flow needs to continue within that specific method, which is why I need to wait there. I can't go on with an event at some later point in time that would start a separate flow (at least not without waiting for that event as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *can* [await UI things such as button clicks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2012/11/28/how-to-await-a-button-click/), doing so is problematic. What if the user does something else, like closing that window? Or click somewhere else?

It's better to design a UX that doesn't constrain the user into a single UI workflow.

Comment: The application is a game, so there are no actual "workflow guidelines" to follow. It would be actually be a bother for a player to have multiple windows popping in and out of existence (which is what I had in the past - this is actually an attempt to get away from that design). If this UserControl comes into play, the only clickable thing is actually the stuff in the UserControl, though other parts of the UI may still be visible.

Closing that window means exiting the game. (And yes, I know that WPF is probably not the best suitable thing for a game in .NET, but I am abusing it anyway :))

Comment: Then again, your link made me aware of the `TaskCompletionSource`, which seems to be doing what I need. I'll give that one a try to see if it works in my scenario.